# difficulty in comparing and assigning datatypes

Tags: javascript, html, css

[to move red box over yellow container - onmouseover-> move right , onmouseout-> move left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJTrE.jpg)

I tried `pos=document.getElementById("animate").style.left;`
then by `setinterval`, I tried to move it using `pos++` and `pos--`. but it didn't work. Please Help.

here's the code.

```js
var id_l, id_r;
function right() {
 clearInterval(id_l);
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
 var pos=box.style.left;
 id_r=setInterval(move,5);
 function move() {
  if(pos==900) {
   clearInterval(id_r);
  }
  else {
      pos++;
      box.style.left = pos + "px";
     }
 }
}
function left() {
 clearInterval(id_r);
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
 var pos=box.style.left;
 id_l=setInterval(move,5);
 function move() {
  if(pos==0) {
   clearInterval(id_l);
  }
  else {
      pos--;
      box.style.left = pos + "px";
     }
 }
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
#animate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
 left: "200px";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">  
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container" onmouseover="right()" onmouseout="left()">
      <div id="animate">
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing it wrong. When you get the position, it gives you in format `100px` etc. You have to trim `px` and then do your computation

```js
var id_l, id_r;
function right() {
 clearInterval(id_l);
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
 var pos=box.style.left;
    pos = pos.toString().substr(0, pos.length-2); // do not read `px`
 id_r=setInterval(move,5);
 function move() {
  if(pos==900) {
   clearInterval(id_r);
  }
  else {
      pos++;
      box.style.left = pos + "px";
     }
 }
}
function left() {
  
 clearInterval(id_r);
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
 var pos=box.style.left;
    pos = pos.toString().substr(0, pos.length-2); // do not read px
   
 id_l=setInterval(left,5);
 function left() {
      
          
      
  if(pos==0) {
      
   clearInterval(id_l);
  }
  else {
      pos--;
      box.style.left = pos+"px";
     }
 }
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
#animate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
 left: "200px";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">  
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container" onmouseover="right()" onmouseout="left()">
      <div id="animate">
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do correct by adding `parseInt` in both `move()` because it's get a string!

> element.style.left is only work in inline style ! so use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is better

```
var pos = window.getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('left');
function move() {
        pos = parseInt(pos);
        if(pos==900) {
            clearInterval(id_r);
        }
        else {
            pos++;
            box.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
    }
```